# Bootstrap's Navbar Dropdown Link won't work

Tags: dropdown, navbar, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap 5 with my Navbar. I have two Dropdown Links for my site and whenever I try to click on the page that holds them (ex. Reviews), it doesn't work. I don't believe I'm missing any Bootstrap links or jQuery to make the Dropdown work.

```
  <div class="container-fluid"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="images-logo/logo.png" alt="Game Picker"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="news.html">News</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown"> <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" aria-current="page" href="previews.html" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> Previews </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" aria-current="page" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" aria-current="page" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" aria-current="page" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown"> <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" aria-current="page" href="reviews.html" id="navbarDropdownMenuLinkTwo" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> Reviews </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLinkTwo">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li></div></div></nav>
```

Comment: [https://jsfiddle.net/wkqgzt0r/1/] If you're talking about the links on the text 'Previews'/'Reviews' itself, they don't work because they are dropdown. You can either make them link to another page, OR make them work as a dropdown. You can't do both.

Comment: Okay, I'd like them to link to another page (e.g. previews.html). Would I just remove the dropdown entirely then?

Comment: You can do two things here. Either remove the dropdown completely and make them links. However I am guessing you do need the dropdown, in that case you might consider using this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/#dropdown-options
In the second example here (the one with 'Reference' text on button), you can use the first part as a link to another page (just change the button to an anchor link), and the second part as a dropdown. Best of both worlds!
Also I had a typo on my link in the first comment, the [] shouldn't be there. Can't edit it now.